# Stopping Angularjs from executing next line

Tags: angularjs

How to tell angular to stop to process for next lines when meet the condition in IF as below.

**CODE**

```
if(!$scope.add.partcode){
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Kartu Stok ...',
      template: 'Silakan pilih part code terlebih dahulu.'
    });
    $ionicLoading.hide();

  }else {
    var Partcode = $scope.add.partcode.part_no;
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Use **return** statement.

Comment: use the `return` statement?

Comment: If you want to stop to process next line (`var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({...`), why you put it inside `if` condition?